# Android: Where can I get the result from the SQLite command?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new for developing Android. May I ask where can I get the result of the sqlite command?

I would like to join 2 tables as follow: But How can I get the result in my application?

Quite confused about that and already search for several topics in google. Now, I can only get the result in the console by using adb shell. But it is meaningless.

```
SELECT Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, SUM(Sales.SaleAmount) AS SalesPerCustomer
FROM Customers JOIN Sales
ON Customers.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName
```

Comment: I want to use the result from two tables to create a new table.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the database object, you can just call

db.query() which will return a Cursor object, which contains the
query results.

here is a nice tutorial that could help you:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite support [CREATE TABLE AS SELECT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) syntax. So try the following sql

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " AS SELECT Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, SUM(Sales.SaleAmount) AS SalesPerCustomer
FROM Customers JOIN Sales
ON Customers.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName";
```

Execute it by:

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
//initialize db
db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
```